# How to say "Should we [do something]?"

Tags: translation, questions

I recently started talking with a Japanese "pen friend" on Skype, and I'd like to ask her "Should we speak in Japanese or English?"

If I said:

> わたしたちは　日本語を　はなしますか。　英語を　はなしますか。

does that convey what I'm trying to say? Or is there a better way to express it?

I would appreciate it if you could reply in kana, I know precious few kanji.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to ask your "pen friend" whether she wants to talk with you in Japanese or English, Don't you?

In this situation, I say "日本語で　はなしますか、それとも英語で　はなしますか？".
This sentence means "Which would you like to speak in? Japanese or English?"

Comment: Okay, I looked up the meaning of それとも, which I haven't heard before. Apparently it means "or else", to connect two alternatives. わかります！ Thanks, I'll accept.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "日本語で　はなすか、それとも英語で　はなしますか？" AFAIK, only the last verb should be in polite form in the sentence?

Comment: @herby, I hadn't heard that before, are you sure?

Comment: You're right, via http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/polite: "The masu-form must always come at the end of a complete sentence and never inside a modifying relative clause. When we learn compound sentences, we will see that each sub-sentence of the compound sentence can end in masu-form as well.", so in compond sentences, as this one, it is ok for both verbs to be polite; it is only about intra-sentence verb clause.

Comment: Why is everyone using spaces here?

Comment: I find it easier to understand, I am vaguely aware that they aren't needed, though. At the moment I'm trying to understand syntax - space-separating word-particle units helps me to remember what the particles do.

Comment: Spaces are often used when there's no kanji at all, and they're occasionally used when there are only a few kanji (as in this question and answer).  It's not how Japanese is normally written, but in my opinion there's nothing wrong with it, especially if it helps you understand.

Comment: That's the other reason - because I understand so few kanji, I use spaces to help me to understand phrase boundaries.

Answer (score 10):

A good structure you might want to look into is the [～ましょう](http://www.renshuu.org/index.php?page=grammar/individual&id=337) verb ending. It means "let's *_*_" You attach ましょう to the verb stem, so for "let's speak" it would be はなしましょう.

To make it "shall we *_*_?" you add "か" to the end. So for "shall we speak?" it would be はなしましょうか？

Comment: +1 Damn, I can't accept two answers ;). Both perfectly valid constructions: I like the simplicity of it. Could I say: `日本語を　はなしましょうか。　それとも　英語を　はなしましょう。`?

Comment: I followed that link, so the form you describe is called the volitional form?

Comment: @LeoKing I think you can say「日本語"で"[話]{はな}しましょうか。それとも英語"で"[話]{はな}しましょう"か"。」

Comment: Does the で particle sound more natural than the を particle?

Comment: @LeoKing the particle を does not work here. The English "Let's speak English" is really "Let's speak [in] English" without the in. The で refers to the means, i.e. [手段]{しゅだん}, that enables the communication.

Comment: Oh, okay. わかります！

Comment: Thank you for your support. I think "~ましょうか" is better than "~ますか" too.

However I think that many Japanese would care less about the difference of the two. If you are nervous about grammer miss, don't be afraid! Many Japanese use their language with many grammatical mistakes.

Comment: I'm not nervous about it, but as a language student I feel like it's my responsibility to learn to speak how Japanese people consider normal.

Comment: @Leo, thanks :) And yes, the volitional. There's a shorter, casual version of it too, once you get used to the long version. (よう・おう)

Answer (score 1):

xxx xx *しょうか*

xxx xx *syouKa*

e.g. ご飯にしま *しょうか*   gohannishima *syouka* (shall we have lunch)

e.g. 日本語で話しま *しょうか* nihongodehanashima *SyoUKa* (should we talk in Japanese)

Comment: -1 I can't take your answer seriously: it's very distracting the way you've capitalised every syllable, and I've not seen "syo" as a romanisation of しょ before.

Comment: sorry but syo=しょ when typing on key

Comment: @LeoKing Without commenting on the answer as a whole, I'll just note that *syo* is fine as a romanization of しょ.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just not used to it. Is it ever pronounced as /sjɒ/ as opposed to /ʃɒ/?

Comment: @LeoKing "Syo" is Nihon Shiki-style romanization, where kana-alphabetic correspondence is more important than pronunciation-alphabetic correspondence. All gojuon kana, with the exception of ん, are represented by two letters. So, for example, し is "si", and つ is "tu". The yoon kana take the base gojuon letter and add "ya", "yu", or "yo". So しょ is  "syo", じょ is "jyo", ちょ is "tyo", etc. It makes for more uniform romanization, but it's not very intuitive in English, so it's not used as widely as Hepburn romanization is.

Comment: @LeoKing You may want to ask that as a separate question.  A couple quick notes: slashes indicate **phonemic** transcription, which in Japanese can be very simple, hardly requiring special characters at all--phonemically しょ could be transcribed /syo/ (as in Labrune 2012).  In contrast, you can indicate **phonetic** transcriptions with square brackets.  And importantly, Japanese has no [ʃ].  Instead, /si/ is typically realized as [ɕi].

Comment: @snailplane I'm in the habit of writing IPA from my A-level English Language course. I don't quite understand the distinction between phonemic and phonetic, but I'm aware that's a different stackexchange, let alone a different question.

Comment: Also, I'm struggling to notice a difference between those two phonemes. One is palato-alveolar and one is alveolo-palatal. How strange.